# RequireJS Map Configuration of Multiple files

Tags: requirejs, require

I have some files, like,

```
test/test1,
test/test2,
test/test3
```

and i want to rename there path to

```
newtest/test1,
newtest/test2,
newtest/test3
```

so that if we try to require the above file, then it will point to new path.

In require, one to one mapping is present, but not sure, if something like this is achievable,

```
require.map = {
  "test/*": "newtest/*",
}
```

Any help :)

Comment: Are you against just renaming the requires in your files perhaps using regex from atom or your text editor of choice?

Comment: Renaming is not possible as there are other libs which are using the provided path and we don't want to change them. Rather a more complex scenario in my case, so need to figure out a way with mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` configuration option supports mapping module prefixes. Here's an example:

```
require.config({
  map: {
    "*": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
});

define("bar/x", function () {
  return "bar/x";
})

require(["foo/x"], console.log);
```

The last `require` call that tries to load `foo/x` will load `bar/x`.

This is as good as it gets for pattern matching with `map`. RequireJS does not support putting arbitrary patterns in there. Using `"test/*": "newtest/*"` would not work. The `"*"` I used in `map` is not a pattern. It is a hardcoded value that means "in all modules", and *happens* to look like a glob pattern. So the `map` above means "in all modules, when `foo` is required, load `bar` instead".

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you really need [map](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map). You can probably just use [paths](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths). Quoting from [map](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) documentation

> This sort of capability is really important for larger projects which
> may have two sets of modules that need to use two different versions
> of 'foo', but they still need to cooperate with each other.

Also see [paths](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) documentation

> Using the above sample config, "some/module"'s script tag will be
> src="/another/path/some/v1.0/module.js".

Here is how [paths](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) can be used to map the directory from test to newtest for your example

```
paths: {
  "test": "newtest"
}
```